# Contar a quantidade de vezes que um caractere aparece numa string

Tags: string, linux, shell-script

Preciso contar a quantidade de vezes que um caractere se repete em uma *string*.

Por exemplo: Quantas vezes o caractere `/` aparece na *string* abaixo?

> '/file/program-files/teste/dev/dev1/Central.pdf.gz'

Essa *string* estará dentro de uma variável `$v_dir_relatorio`.

Preciso da quantidade de barras para criar uma lógica de busca de arquivos em diretórios que os caminhos variam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa é remover os caracteres que você não quer, usando `//[^\/]`, após isso basta contar os caracteres remanescentes:

```
v_dir_relatorio="'/file/program-files/teste/dev/dev1/Central.pdf.gz"
quantidade="${v_dir_relatorio//[^\/]}"

echo "${#quantidade}"  # 6
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMHM3UzA5SFZSdE0)</kbd>

Comment: Muito obrigado stderr, exatamente isso que precisava! \o/

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $v_dir_relatorio | grep -o / | wc -l
```

1. `echo` para passar algo para o pipeline, neste caso `$v_dir_relatorio`
2. `grep` para buscar um padrão, neste caso o caractere '/'. A opção `-o` imprime cada 'match' encontrado em uma linha.
3. `wc` para contar. Com `-l` ele conta a quantidade de linhas, que coincide com a quantidade de 'matches' encontrados.

Comment: Muito obrigado Genos! Funcionou perfeitamente, mas só posso marcar como solução uma resposta, valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Em shell script (bash) uma das alternativas pode ser:

```
echo "/1/2/3/4" | grep -o '/' | wc -l
```

Para o seu caso:

```
v_dir_relatorio=`echo "$CAMINHO" | grep -o '/' | wc -l`
```

Encontrei outras respostas válidas em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679369/count-occurrences-of-char-in-string-using-bash

Comment: Muito obrigado Osmar! Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Já agora usando Perl:

```
perl -nE 'say tr!/!!' <<< $v_dir_relatorio
```

O comando `tr` (que transforma o conjunto de caracteres do primeiro grupo no correspondente do segundo) devolve o número de caracteres encontrados.